# How to 'dot' in an environment file in Python

Tags: python

I wrote a Python program which will be executed on both the Primary Production server, as well on the Disaster Recovery server. There is a slight difference in behavior when the program is run on the Disaster Recovery server.
Therefore the program needs to determine which server it is running on.

We have many other ksh programs running on these servers, which have the same requirement: run on both servers, but there could be a slight difference on the DR server. All of these scripts 'dot' in an environment file, then check " if environment variable $DR_SITE equal 1" to determine if its running on the DR server.

I want to use the existing environment file from my Python program - to determine if it is running on the DR server. I can not just read the this environment file, it is actually a ksh script that itself has some logic prior to setting the DR_SITE variable.

Which brings me to the original question:
How do you 'dot' in (or execute an environment file as described above in python, in order to inherit the environment variables set by the ?
For example, in `ksh` I would execute this:

```
. /path/env.set
```

I tried this, but it did not seem to work (I printed out the DR_SITE value before calling the os.system call, and after, it did not change):

```
os.system(". /appl/gfpd2/current/D2soe_set")
```

Comment: "But it did not seem to work." How can you tell? Are you getting an error, or...?

Comment: What do you expect the file to do? `os.system()` executes the command in a subshell, but then that subshell is closed again.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Load environment variables? Or are you trying to execute a shell script?

Comment: Sounds like you want to source the file, which would be loading environment variables. But yes, these wouldn't stay around when os.system() finishes.

Comment: You can't do exactly what you want. You could have a different configuration file that Python can load, or parse the file directly in Python setting `os.environ`, or wrap the invocation of the Python script in a bash script that sources the environment first, or run a subshell that sources the script, then prints out the environment variables and Python parses them. But sourcing an rc file in the general case is specific to the shell it was written for; they can do a ton of things beyond merely setting the environment, and general purpose sourcing of non-Python code makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a `ksh` script that sources and executes the environment setter and then invokes the Python program;

```
#!/usr/bin/env ksh
. /path/env.set
exec python /path/your_script.py
```

Exec is used to save some memory.
(I'm omitting the passing of variables to the Python script since I'm not familiar with `ksh`.)